# Gettings a list of values where id is the same as another column form another table

Tags: mysql

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with this query?

I have tried this query, it worked when not putting "WHERE b.can_sell=1" but then it stopped working after putting that?

```
SELECT a.*
from user_guns a INNER JOIN
     craft_guns b
     ON a.gun_id=b.gun_id
WHERE b.Can_Sell = 1;
```

When I say stopped working, I mean it selects nothing when it should..

Comment: You're sure there are records with `can_sell` equal to 1 in `craft_guns`?

Comment: There are no records that match the `where` clause, obviously.  Perhaps if you edit your question and include some sample data, we better understand what is happening.